# LSTM, val_loss error causing model not to save, why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter, lstm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0k-YLQGKjY

LSTM, Keras jupyter notebook on ppc and colab same error.

```
cp = ModelCheckpoint('model1/', save_best_only=True)

model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

model1.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10, callbacks=[cp])

Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 98.6413 - root_mean_squared_error: 9.9318
WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_loss available, skipping.
```

When I train the model the warning appears 'save best model only with val_loss'.
val_loss is not displayed in the epoch, only X_val and y_val so it is not using val_loss as a monitor. I tried adding it in different ways but it won't let me

In the video link to the tutorial he has loss, root_mean_squared_error, val_loss, val_root_mean_squared_error

I have gone over the code and it looks perfect, what else could it be?

Comment: thousands of possible reasons, 5 meaningless likes of code without an explanation...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mjjvc, I was not able to replicate the issue in colab, kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/9e121a180afc7dc028ddb49fa57b3ef5/copy-of-lstm-time-series-forecasting.ipynb). Thank you!